# SQL remove part of field

Tags: sql

I have a field which is a list of numbers separated by commas like following :

```
001,002,003...
```

I would like to update my field by removing one of these numbers like this :

```
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE (column, '002', '')
```

I will have this :
     001,,003...
My probleme is with commas, because I don't know if my number is at the beginning of my field, in the middle or at the end. So I can't do something like :

```
UPDATE table SET column = REPLACE (column, '002,', '')
```

Any sugestion? Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: The solution: **stop** using multiple, comma-separated values in a single column! It's against even the **first** normal form of database design

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
UPDATE table 
     SET column = SUBSTRING( 
                             REPLACE (',' + column, ',002', '')
                 , 2, 10000)
```

or you can use STUFF to just remove the first char.

Comment: If you have "002, 003" that will give you "02, 003", that's a problem

Comment: @user3884887: No, that will give you ' 003' and that's correct. Besides your question stated "001,002,003...", no spaces in there. If you (wrongly) have spaces in there, you'll just have to add a replace(field, ' ', ''). Another reason why you should normalize your database design. If you use mysql, and it's substring starts at index 0 instead of 1, you'll have to use Substring(..., 1, 10000)